# Pass an output of stdout(jmeter) and pass it as variable string to another sampler

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

This  is my scenario I'm running a java program in bean shell sampler in j meter and getting the required string in STD OUT console. Even i have successfully wrote the required string to a output file. I need to extract the string from the file or console and pass it to other samples(the required string is present along with lot of information in the output so i need to extract string like "Required String:following Character"   Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## When ever You need to direct a output Use this following code

> ```
> System.setOut(new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new
> FileOutputStream("path/to/file/output.txt")), true));
> ```

Say I'm Calling a external java file which is included in test plan (as some jar file)

Write This code in Beanshell Sampler

> ```
> import userdir.UserClass;
>
> UserClass obj1 =new UserClass(); obj1.method1();
>
> System.setOut(new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new
> FileOutputStream("path/to/file/output.txt")), true));
> ```

Now whatever ouput is produced by Userclass in STD OUT will be directed to the ouput.txt

## Code to Extract the required string in Beanshell Post Processor from the file ouput.txt

> ```
> import java.io.FileNotFoundException;   
> import java.util.Scanner;   
> import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;
>
> File file = new File("path/to/file/output.txt");  
> String word = "Req String1";  
> String word2 = "Req String2";  
> Scanner scanner = null;  
> String line;   
> String s1;  
> String s2;     
> try {
>    scanner = new Scanner(file); }    
>   catch(FileNotFoundException e) {     //handle this }
>
>  //now read the file line by line     
>
>  while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {  
> line = scanner.nextLine();
>
> if(line.contains(word)) {   
>    log.info(line);  
>    s1=line;    
>   //now the entire line along with Req String1 will be stored in s1
> }
>
> if(line.contains(word2)) { 
>   log.info(line);
>    s2=line;
> }
>  }
>
> log.info("The value in Encrypt str  ="+s1);  
> log.info("The value in Signatr str  ="+s2);  
> String[] s1 = s1.split(":");  
> String[] s2 =s2.split(":");  
> //since my value in the line is Req String1:needed data
>
> props.put("s1",s1[1]);  
> props.put("s2",s2[1]);
>
> log.info("The value in ORIGINAL Req String1  ="+props.get("s1"));
> log.info("The value in ORIGINAL Req String2  ="+props.get("s2"));
> scanner.close();
> ```

Hope this is useful to all

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 options:

1. Run your program using [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) instead of Beanshell Sampler, this way you will be able to get the output like from any other sampler and extract "interesting" part of the response using [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor).
2. If you cannot or don't want to change current implementation you can read your file contents into a JMeter Variable using [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) and again use the aforementioned Regular Expression Extractor to fetch the data you need from the variable.